# Azure Table Storage access time - inserting/reading from

Tags: azure, insert, storage, import-from-csv

I'm making a program that stores and reads from Azure tables some that are stored in CSV files. What I got are CSV files that that can have various number of columns, and between 3k and 50k rows. What I need to do is upload that data in Azure table. So far I managed to both upload data and retrieve it.
I'm using REST API, and for uploading I'm creating XML batch request, with 100 rows per request. Now that works fine, except it takes a bit too long to upload, ex. for 3k rows it takes around 30seconds. Is there any way to speed that up? I noticed that it takes most time when proccessing response ( for `ReadToEnd()` command ). I read somewhere that setting proxy to null could help, but it doesn't do much in my case.

I also found somewhere that it is possible to upload whole XML request to blob and then execute it from there, but I couldn't find any example for doing that.

```
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) 
        { 
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {
                String responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

As for retrieving data from azure tables, I managed to get 1000 entities per request. As for that, it takes me around 9s for CS with 3k rows. It also takes most time when reading from stream. When I'm calling this part of the code (again `ReadToEnd()` ):

```
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Any tips?

Comment: Are you testing cloud to cloud or local dev. environment to cloud?

Comment: Those where for local to cloud, when i moved application to cloud it worked much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using REST API you may have to write extra code and depend on your own methods to implement performance improvement differently then using client library. In your case using Storage client library would be best as you can use already build features to expedite insert, upsert etc as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/09/15/windows-azure-tables-introducing-upsert-and-query-projection.aspx).

However if you were using Storage Client Library and ADO.NET you can use the article below which is written by Windows Azure Table team as supported way to improve Azure Access Performance:

[.NET and ADO.NET Data Service Performance Tips for Windows Azure Tables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/d84ba34b-b0e0-4961-a167-bbe7618beb83/)

Comment: I found those tips for improving performance, i am now trying to improve it using threads.